# Pushing infromation in sql lite database

Tags: android, sql, database

I want to store a data base in my android emulator. I have a datasheet .In asp we can view the database data by clicking show table data . And we can also edit that data. But i want to do that in my android emulator.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are enough tutorials available on using databases on Android. Use Google to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native GUI available in emulator for manipulating SQLite database. However, the easiest and best way is to access your database in emulator via **ADB**. For example:

Open command prompt and type the following (make sure you have defined Android SDK's *platform-tools* in your path)

```
adb shell
```

and you should see `#` symbol, then:

```
sqlite3 data/data/your_package_name/databases/your_database_name
```

For more details, read **[this](http://bradchow.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/sqlite-command-in-adb/)**.